# Find the best way to implement a 'like' logic in firebase and flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, data-structures

i have a question.
I develop a feature waht user allow to like a task.

For example:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The user can klick on the icon heart.
If he click on the icon the color change and the number below go up (1 => 2).

Now i want build my database structure in firebase but im not sure waht is the best way (for performance...).

My idea:
[image]

I want create a task_id where i add a title, description, total count of viewer etc...
In the task_id i put also a the user_id to check the user has vote the task before.
To check the user is contain in the task i want use a collectionGroup.

I'm new in firebase and i don't know how much the performance is influenced.

Maybe anyone find a other or better way to check the user hast vote the task.

Many thx (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for your document model of task would be to use subcollections as suggested by the  [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections):

```
{
    "taskId1": {
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "title": "Task 1",
        "totalLikes": 2,
        "likes": {
            "userId1": {
                "liked": 1,
                "datetime": "2021-08-04T13:33:03.969Z"
            },
            "userId2": {
                "liked": -1,
                "datetime": "2021-08-09T21:47:03.857Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get the total likes variable, you could update the counter when a user gives a like, writing the proper security rules to ensure that the like count matches.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "likes": {
            "$thing": {
                "$userId": {
                    ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
                    ".validate": "data.isNumber() && data.val() >= -1 && data.val() <= 1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thx for your answer. Thats a nice idea. I will try it out (: Many thx